# Speed up GarageBand track and pitch the sound

Tags: macos, audio, garageband

I recorded some songs form an old tape. Because it was running a bit slower, everything sounds lower.

I want to speed up the things, but without keeping the same tonality. I want to change the speed, but same time I want to make the sounds to sound higher (transposing/pitching everything a bit higher).

How can I do that in GarageBand?

I did change the tempo, but it is smart enough to keep the same tonality. How can I tell it to ignore that?

Comment: What's wrong with using a separate pitch control?

Comment: @JMY1000 How can I do that? In my case it would be easier just to *resize* the track because I know what's the expected time of the tape (but obviously it took longer to be recorded because it was slower).

Comment: Untested, but something like [this](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=qZiJotIWgeM) appears to work.

Comment: @JMY1000 Thanks–I already tried that, but it doesn't work at all for some reason. Also, that doesn't change the length of the track. Basically I want the inverse of the slowness of my tape player: decrease the length (time) while increasing the pitch automatically (which should be natural–without editing it particularly).

Comment: That's weird, it might be worth making a second question. I understand that an ideal solution would be tied to the time, but I'm not sure how to do that, so I was trying to add a make do solution.